# Regex get the matched token

Tags: javascript, regex

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I am making a regular expression to clean some text inputed through rich text editor.
The Regular expression is bellow:

```
<[input|iframe][^<>]*\/>|
<table[^<]+width\s*=\s*"\w*".*>
```

What i want is the follow :
  When the html element `<table>` with an 'width' attribute is matched like this

```
<table width="30px">...
```

I want to clean the 'width' attribute to get the following result:

```
<table>
```

The others situations are the second regular expression alternation

If an `<iframe ../>` or `<input .../>` are matched then all the text is cleared.

Example :

```
   <p>Text</p>
   <iframe .../>
   <div><span>Text</span></div>
```

Result:

```
<p>Text</p>
<div><span>Text</span></div>
```

I already have the regular expression working well i guess,and now im missing the javascript programmatic side. 
I know that there is two methods "search" and "replace" that works with regular expressions, but the search method will return the beginning index of the matched text just like this for instance

```
<p>Test</p><table width="30px"><tr>
```

search method will return 12 ("The index of the `<t`") element.
Is there any way to return the "width='*'" element to replace directly ?
Because the regular expressiom is made of two alternations , how do i know which one was matched ?

Thanks in advance

Sorry for the long text but i am tring to be the most explicit.

Best regards

Comment: `.*>` will include any tags in the same line following the table in the table.  You probably want a negative charset or a non-greedy match.

Comment: You can use regex101 to see the javascript generated code for you regex. Here you have the link http://regex101.com/r/qL6yG7/1 go to `Code Generator`